# Flutter App Navigation from Notifications Not Working as Expected

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, flutter-local-notification

I'm currently developing a Flutter app and I'm running into some problems with handling notifications and navigation within the app.

The app is receiving notifications correctly, but there are issues with how navigation is being handled based on the app's state. Here are the scenarios:

- If the app is in the foreground, the notification arrives but the app doesn't navigate to the correct screen.
- If the app is in the background, the app navigates to the correct screen when the notification is tapped.
- If the app is terminated, tapping the notification does open the app but it doesn't navigate to the correct screen.

Here's the relevant code snippet from my `notification_handler.dart`:

```
const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel', // id
  'High Importance Notifications', // title
  description: 'This is the description', // description
  importance: Importance.high,
  playSound: true
);

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('A bg message just showed up :  ${message.messageId}');
}

const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
  AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
  InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);

void notificationHandler(context) {
  void dealWithMessage(RemoteMessage? message) async {
    RemoteNotification notification = message!.notification!;
    AndroidNotification android = message.notification!.android!;
    if (notification != null && android != null) {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(channel.id, channel.name,
                color: Colors.black,
                playSound: true,
                icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
                importance: Importance.max,
                priority: Priority.high),
          ));
    }
    if (message.data.keys.length != 0) {
      if (message.data['intent'] == 'comment') {
        var postSlug = message.data['post_slug'];
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => PostDetailScreen(postSlug: postSlug)));
      }
      // other code omitted for brevity...
    }
  }

  Future selectNotification(String? payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(payload);
      RemoteMessage message = RemoteMessage.fromMap(data);
      dealWithMessage(message);
    }
  }

  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: selectNotification);

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    RemoteNotification notification = message.notification!;
    AndroidNotification android = message.notification!.android!;
    if (notification != null && android != null) {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(channel.id, channel.name,
                color: Colors.black,
                playSound: true,
                icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
                importance: Importance.max,
                priority: Priority.high),
          ),
          payload: jsonEncode(message.data));
    }
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
    print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
    dealWithMessage(message);
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
    dealWithMessage(message);
  });
}
```

I expected that upon receiving a notification while the app is in the foreground, the app would navigate to the `PostDetailScreen` (or relevant screen based on the intent type in the notification data), after tapping.

I attempted to achieve this by using `Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PostDetailScreen(postSlug: postSlug)));` within my `dealWithMessage` function which is called when a notification is received.

However, this is not working as expected. When a notification is received, no navigation occurs. The app stays on the current screen and does not navigate to the `PostDetailScreen` or any other screen.

I have also checked that `message.data['post_slug']` has the expected value, and it does. The `PostDetailScreen` exists and is working correctly when navigated to from other parts of the app.

Answer (score 0):

You expected that `upon receiving a notification while the app is in the foreground, the app would navigate to the PostDetailScreen (or relevant screen based on the intent type in the notification data).`  **without tap on notification**, then you should call `dealWithMessage(message)` into `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen`.

Comment: Apologies, and thanks for the response. I should have phrased that better. I meant that it should navigate upon tapping.

I had tried the flow you mentioned in the response, and it does work and it navigates it as soon as a notification arrives. Navigation after tapping is where it's not working.

Comment: Ok, So when `If the app is in the foreground, the notification arrives` and you `tap on it`, can you got `print` statement of `FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen` method at your `console` or not ?

Comment: I can see the print statement. So it's definitely getting triggered.

Comment: Sorry, for late reply, It is nice that you `getting triggered`. I faced same issue in past, after debugging and trace my all flow  of navigate other page, after tap on notification, then I found a place in one method there are `value update` or became `null` of `message.data['xxx']`, so after tap on notification not able to navigate properly at particular page. So you will have to same things.